# Using unity my js file is not working to pick things up?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

Ok to make it short I have a js file and it goes through child directories and everything, And I use the child directories for organizational purposes, now it works without using the child directories, Ill show code for with and without...

---

Without child directories (working but less organized)

```
var target : Transform;

function Update () 
{

}

function OnMouseDown() 
{
    this.transform.position = target.position;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;

}


function OnMouseUp() 
{
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = null;
}
```

---

And the child directory code (Not working more organized)

```
var target : Transform;

function Update () 
{

}

function OnMouseDown() 
{
    this.transform.position = target.position;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("World001").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;
}


function OnMouseUp() 
{
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("World001").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Village001").transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, but I am confused by your spread of curly braces. Normally I would put your second brace '}' as the last brace in the code, *acting as 'bookends'* for your function. Your OnMouseUp() and OnMouseDown() are sub-routines embedded in a larger function, and the braces for 'Update()' act as a wrapper for the main function call and any embedded routines. The more complex version of your code may be bringing this issue forward.
Update()
{

OnMouseUp()
{
Sub-routine code;
}

OnMouseDown()
{
Sub-routine code;
}

}
End of function
Also I do not understand your function inside of a function layout. For this to work both the main and a subroutine would have to be called at the same time, unless 'Update()' is embedded inside a loop so it checks for calls to your subroutines at given intervals.

Comment: I don't completely understand what your saying, though if I'm correct your saying I need my OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown function in the update function?

Comment: I will check this our thanks for the info I'm new to javascript and unity. Java is where I work the most decided instead of using LWJGL I'll try something different

Comment: Yes, make sure their embedded between the main function tags, then check both types of code again. By putting the closing brace right after the starting brace you created a 'quirk' that some browsers will ignore, but not when the program is more complex. Think of the braces as bookends for both the main and embedded programs.

Comment: Main function is that the Update function and using the more complex code encasing it in the Update function generates errors

Comment: The miss-placed right brace is at least one error. Clear that issue up and see if you still get errors and what they are.

Comment: Your talking about the update right bracket correct?

Comment: So you don't have to wait if you are talking about the update bracket I get 4 errors when doing this, the first is "expecting (, found 'OnMouseDown'."   The second is "';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end."  The third is "expecting (, found 'OnMouseUp'." the forth is "';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end."

Comment: Correct. View the brace layout I posted above. I do not see any other syntax errors.

Comment: I'm using the layout your suggested above I get errors that way, I don't see them either but Unity does

Comment: You may need a ';' (semi-colon) just before the last brace. I cannot test this code as I do not have the entities you have named. We may have to take this discussion to chat.

Comment: And what do you mean by Function inside Function layout?